# Add Method in MySqlParameter is throwing error

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector, database-connection

I am trying to query the MySql Database from the C# application. Below is the piece of code I am using

```
public class GetNameController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetName(string J_No)
    {
        List<MySqlParameter> prms = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        prms.Add(new MySqlParameter("J_No", MySqlDbType.VarChar, J_No, ParameterDirection.Input));

        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB-connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection dbconn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
            var strQuery = "SELECT * from Name_View where where Number = :J_No ";
```

I have done like this earlier with the Oracle DB connections. But with the above code I am getting error in the `prms.Add()` like

`The best overloaded method match for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.MySqlParameter(string, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType, int, string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: The `int` parameter (where you are stuffing the `J_No` string)  is the size (length) of the varchar. It is not the value of the parameter which is what I assume you are trying to use it for.

Comment: @Crowcoder how would I pass the string in to the Add()

Comment: I prefer to create the parameter then set it's `Value` property. You should avoid using `AddWithValue` if you come across it or someone suggests it.